# Run asp.net VB script AFTER page is closed

Tags: asp.net, service

First, let me thank you for your time.
Platforms: server2008 R2 IIS7 64bit and a second box running server 2008 for SQL.

Ive been attempting to find a solution to a problem I am anticipating so let me explain.

Ill be building a web application that once is done it will send email to a list of subscribed accounts.

I **NEED** to have the client, click a button to fire the script and then be able to close the page while the script continues to run.

The script will be running a timed event (after 100 emails have been sent, wait 10 minutes, send next batch).

This will be a very long lived script.  The "wait to send" is a prerequisite of the client, cant be changed.

I would like to also build a page that will display the status of the script thats running if they liked to check the progress.  Not necessary but thought it would be a nice touch.

So my question is, what are my option at this point.

Ive though about learning how to run this from a service, which I am currently unfamiliar with.
Any incite would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

YOu should ideally think of designing your solution to work with windows services or make async calls to web services.

Comment: Ok, I am still new to a lot of things so let me ask the question.   Web services, that would be an asmx page.  This is something that runs continuously.  I did read about it, but didnt fully grasp it.